# jQuery: Adding text to an existing dynamic HREF

Tags: jquery, href

I am trying to amend a link using jQuery. The links are dynamically generated and I have no control over the existing HREF as they are called from a 3rd party site.

Using jQuery, how can I change a link from this:

```
example.com/?one=1&two=1
```

to this:

```
example.com/?one=1&two=1&thisisadded=true
```

so essentially adding `&thisisadded=true` to the end of the link?

The links which need changing are within their own div with a class of `my-link`.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('a.my-link').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', href + '&thisisadded=true');
});
```

Replace selector with a jQuery selector that will match appropriate link on your site if mine is not good enought.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!

This worked for me and correctly added the "&thisisadded=true" text.

Is it possible to strip paramaters ("&preview=1&TB_iframe=true") out of the link?

I'm opening the links in a new tab and I don't want / need them there.

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 2):

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
 $(this).attr('href', href + '&thisisadded=true')
```

Obviously do this in an context where `this` is your link

Comment: `$(this)` will work in callback once you match all links that needs to be changed. But if you just call your code like this it won't give you the results you'd expect.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mentioned too, that you should be in that context, this can be used on any event on that element, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use your selector, and a callback function to [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr). This will add the additional part to every matching link:

```
$('a.my_link').attr('href', function(i, a){ return a + "&thisadded=true" });
```

When supplying a callback to the `attr` method, the first parameter is the `index` and the second parameter is the original `attribute` value. Whatever is returned from the callback becomes the new value.

**Note:** This feature is available in **jQuery 1.1** and later. Don't get this method confused with the new batch of methods that accept callbacks introduced in jQuery 1.4.

Comment: This is working, But when you click on other links it keeps appending the value to the link. any ideas?